# Count and group by date should return 0 on no values

Tags: mysql, count, group-by

I'm trying to report the number of interviews we did per day.

So I have a table of interviews
such as

interviewid,staffid,date,comments...

and a date reference table containing all date from 2005 to 2020. having a single date field named ref.

My query is :

```
SELECT count(*) as cnt FROM `interviews` 
right JOIN `dateRef` ON `date` = ref where type = 2 
and date > date_sub(now(),interval 7 day) group by date_format(ref,'%Y-%m-%d')
```

Is works fine to display the interview we did but not when we did not do any interviews...

For example this returns :

```
1
2
4
```

But it should return

```
0
1
0
2
0
4
0
```

EDIT:

Apparently the problems comes from the where clause because if I remove it, the query works fine...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try replace to

```
right join
```

instead

```
left join
```

another change is

```
where type = 2
```

to

```
where type = 2 OR type IS NULL
```

SO the final query

```
SELECT count(*) as cnt FROM `interviews` 
right JOIN `dateRef` ON `date` = ref where (type = 2 OR type is null)
and date > date_sub(now(),interval 7 day) group by date_format(ref,'%Y-%m-%d')
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, `type` is a column of interviews. Your joined table contains rows for dates without interviews since you are using a right join, but these rows have `NULL` in the column `type` (and any other column of `interviews`) since there are no entries for these dates in the `interviews` table. They are filtered out by your `WHERE` clause which requires `type=2`, which is why `COUNT` does not see them.

You may try something like `WHERE (type=2 OR type IS NULL)`, at least if `interviews.type` is never `NULL`.